# Change phpinfo background color and bug 24095

Tags: php, html, css

Perhaps out of ignorance I was amazed to find myself unable to change an html page body colour upon calling `phpinfo()`.

Further investigation has led me to think that this must be related to bug 24095 (http://www.justskins.com/forums/24095-com-phpinfo-styles-25807.html).

In other words this will not work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page: info PHP</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>

        body { background-color: darkGray;}

        #presentation
        {
            width:500px;
            height: 140px;
            text-align: center;
            color: lightGray;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 40px;
            background-color: darkGray;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id='presentation'>
            <h2>Info about PHP</h2>
            <p>
            See hereunder the current settings for your server
        </div>
        <? echo phpinfo();  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So how can I change the page body colour upon calling `phpinfo()`?

Comment: You would be well-advised to take a look at my own answer. Too bad for you if you do not care.

Comment: Amazing… Someone here to whom I replied in due time (see my previous comment) argued that my post was irrelevant and down-voted it but… his initial comment has disappeared. Thinkpol?

Answer (score 0):

This code is a fairly simple workaround based on css:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page: info PHP</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>

        body { background-color: darkGray; margin: 0 0 0 0;}

        #zPHP { background-color: darkGray; }

        #presentation
        {
            width:500px;
            height: 140px;
            text-align: center;
            color: lightGray;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: -20px;
            padding-top: 40px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='zPHP'>
        <div id='presentation'>
            <h2>Info about PHP</h2>
            <p>
            See hereunder the current settings for your server
        </div>
        <? echo phpinfo();  ?>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it can help some.